# ListView.addHeader with CursorAdapter and CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I'm using a ListView with a `CursorLoader` to load my records on it. For taht I set the adapter of the ListView with a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. I read on the doc that adding an header to the List with `addHeaderView(View)`, wrapped my adapter to an HeaderListViewAdapter. Doing this, I'm not able to cast the adapter to a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and using `swapCursor()` on it when CursorLoader's `onLoadFinished` gets called.

Here's the code that's throwing the exception:

```
((SimpleCursorAdapter)mDrawerListView.getAdapter()).swapCursor(enhancedCursor);
```

It says that HeaderLsitView cannot be cast to a `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Is there anyway to disable that wrapping in order to use the swap cursor on my ListView adapter?

Comment: What's stopping you from calling `getWrappedAdapter()` to retrieve the `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that method: So I should modify the call like:        ((SimpleCursorAdapter)((WrapperListAdapter)mDrawerListView.getAdapter()).getWrappedAdapter()).swapCursor(enhancedCursor); right?

Comment: You want `HeaderListAdapter` not `WrapperListAdapter`.

Comment: I SimpleCursorAdapter for using swapCursor. Anyway, your answer is correct. Post it as answer and I will accept it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you get back a `HeaderListAdapter` when calling `getAdapter()` on your `ListView` you can still get the underlying `SimpleCursorAdapter` by calling the `getWrappedAdapter()` method on the `HeaderListAdapter`.